# How to make an Order By a field but with a condition inside?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Please masters, I have three table, that I need to select data from using a `LEFT JOIN`; 
and that I need to order by a field **q** (that exists in `table3`) but only where state = 1 (that exists also in `table3`).

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT * FROM table 1
         LEFT JOIN table2 ON x = y
         LEFT JOIN table3 ON z=w
         WHERE w = 1
         ORDER BY q IN ( SELECT q FROM table3 WHERE state = 1);
```

Please any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How abt this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 1
         LEFT JOIN table2 ON x = y
         LEFT JOIN table3 ON z=w
         WHERE w = 1
         ORDER BY case when state=1 then 0 else 1 end,q
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT q FROM table3 WHERE state = 1) as sort_order
FROM table 1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON x = y
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON z=w
WHERE w = 1
ORDER BY sort_order
```

As I do not know what the desired result should be, possibly this is the right query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.x = t2.y
    LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 ON t2.z = t3.w AND t3.state = 1
WHERE t3.w = 1
ORDER BY t3.q
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM table 1
         LEFT JOIN table2 ON x = y
         LEFT JOIN table3 ON z=w
         WHERE w = 1 AND table3.state = 1
         ORDER BY q
```